# HTML character sets & MySQL character sets

Tags: mysql, html

Which HTML character set would cover all these?  Which character set do I need in MySQL to export and then import them?

> SAINT RAPHAEL ARNÁIZ BARÓN  (Spanish)
>
> St Thérèse of the Child Jesus, Virgin, Doctor (French)
>
> M. Orsola (Giulia) Ledóchowska, Religious (Eastern European)

Comment: What do you mean "export and then import them"?

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, use the UTF-8 character set. This will allow you to represent a very wide variety of data appropriately in your DBMS.  If you use your mySQL collation settings correctly, MySql will collate (sort) your info nicely as well.

To render this stuff into HTML, you probably need to entitize characters other than the basic 7-bit ASCII ones.  For example, look at this web page describing the Unicode character for uppercase Ñ    http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00D1/index.htm

In HTML this is represented by ampersand poundsign x d 1 semicolon

Your web app language (PHP? Java?) has functions built in to convert between UTF-8 strings (to stash in the DBMS) and entitized html (for display on the web).  Use them.

Answer (score 0):

Use MySQL's UTF-8 character set for your tables and columns, and send a `SET NAMES UTF8` statement after initialising the MySQL connection in your scripting language of choice. Ensure your script also sends a HTTP header indicating that your page is in UTF-8, and you should be good to go. You may want to read [this](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-changing-encoding), and the links for further reading look good too.

In PHP, to send this HTTP header, you would use 
`header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");`. At the top of your `<head>` element in your HTML page, you can also add `<meta charset="UTF-8">` (in HTML5), or `<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">` (in HTML 4.01 or HTML5; but you can't use both ways and still get valid HTML5).